# To speed up C-code random selection with further modification array

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to write some code in C-language. The main idea is that I have an input linear array that consists the readius for each pixel (`````` - something like that, moreover, the length of `pix_r`, for instance, for picture with size `(128,512)` will be `128 * 512`). And I need for each radius random selected fixed numbers of pixels and other set to `-1`. What I mean:
`r = 2` in `pix_r = [1, 8, 2, 2, 4, 6, 7, 7, 8, 2, 8]` is in the following positions `currentR = [2, 3, 9]`, and let's `NumberOfRandomS = 2`, so one of the possible result can be `pix_r = [*, *, 2, -1, *, *, *, *, *, 2, *]`. and the same should be doe for each r. If number of `items == r` is less than `NumberOfRandomS`, we should pick up all elements without any modification.

I try to write this in C-code. But I am a newbie and don't know all features and tips for optimization. My first aprroach of writing this function is

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


const int NumberOfRandomS = 5;


void RandomSelected(size_t numEl, int maxRad, int *pix_r){
  srand(time(NULL));
  int lenRandomIndex = NumberOfRandomS*sizeof(int);
  int* RandomIndex = (int*) malloc(lenRandomIndex);
  memset(RandomIndex, 0, lenRandomIndex);
  
  int lenNumPerShell1 = (maxRad) * sizeof(int);
  int* numPerShell1 =  (int*) malloc(lenNumPerShell1);
  memset(numPerShell1, 0, lenNumPerShell1);
  
  //Calculate the number of each pix_r per shell
  for (int i=0; i<numEl; ++i){
    numPerShell1[pix_r[i]]++;
  }
  
  //Main part for random selection of NumberOfRandomS items 
  //for each pix_r
  for(int r=0; r<maxRad; ++r){
    int lenShellR = numPerShell1[r];

    //if number of items for this r is less than should be
    //selected, skip it. It means that we selected all items 
    //for this r
    if(lenShellR <= NumberOfRandomS){
      continue;
    }

    int lenCurrentR = lenShellR*sizeof(int);
    int* currentR = (int *) malloc(lenCurrentR); // array of indexes for this r
    memset(currentR, 0, lenCurrentR);
    
    //filling currentR array with all indexes for this r
    int cInd = 0;
    for(register int j=0; j<numEl; ++j){
      if(pix_r[j] == r){
        currentR[cInd] = j;
        cInd++;
      }
    }

    //generate random indexes without repetiotion that should be selected from currentR
    //this indexes help us to save r value in these positions and others indexes for this r
    //set to -1
    int value[NumberOfRandomS];
    for (int i=0;i<NumberOfRandomS;++i)
    {
        int check; //variable to check or index is already used for this r
        size_t pick_index; //variable to store the random index in
        do
        {
        
        pick_index = rand() % lenShellR;
        //check or index is already used for this r:
        check=1;
        for (int j=0;j<i;++j)
            if (pick_index == value[j]) //if index is already used
            {
                check=0; //set check to false
                break; //no need to check the other elements of value[]
            }
        } while (check == 0); //loop until new, unique index is found
        value[i]=pick_index; //store the generated index in the array
        RandomIndex[i] = currentR[pick_index];
    }

    //set all positions for each r that are not on random selected to -1
    for(register int k=0; k < lenShellR; ++k)
    {
      int flag = 0; // flag will be 1 if this index for this r in RandomIndex
      for (register int q = 0; q < NumberOfRandomS; ++q) 
      { 
        if(RandomIndex[q] == currentR[k])
        {
          flag = 1; //this index is found
        }
      }
      if(flag != 1)
      {
        //index for this r not in RandomIndex, so set this index for this r to -1
        pix_r[currentR[k]] = -1; 
      }
    }

  }
  return;
}
```

I tried to optimize a little bit, but different resources contradict each other and after testing it didn't show any speeding up:

```
void ModRandomSelected(size_t numEl, int maxRad, int *pix_r){
  srand(time(NULL));
  int lenRandomIndex = NumberOfRandomS*sizeof(int);
  int* RandomIndex = (int*) malloc(lenRandomIndex);
  memset(RandomIndex, 0, lenRandomIndex);
  
  int lenNumPerShell1 = (maxRad) * sizeof(int);
  int* numPerShell1 =  (int*) malloc(lenNumPerShell1);
  memset(numPerShell1, 0, lenNumPerShell1);
  
  //Calculate the number of each pix_r per shell
  for (int i=numEl-1; i>=0; --i){
    numPerShell1[pix_r[i]]++;
  }
  
  //Main part for random selection of NumberOfRandomS items 
  //for each pix_r
  for(int r=maxRad-1; r>=0; --r)
  {
    int lenShellR = numPerShell1[r];

    //if number of items for this r is less than should be
    //selected, skip it. It means that we selected all items 
    //for this r
    if(lenShellR <= NumberOfRandomS){
      continue;
    }

    int lenCurrentR = lenShellR*sizeof(int);
    int* currentR = (int *) malloc(lenCurrentR); // array of indexes for this r
    memset(currentR, 0, lenCurrentR);

    //filling currentR array with all indexes for this r
    int cInd = 0;
    for(register int i = numEl-1; i>=0; --i)
    {
      if(pix_r[i] == r){
        currentR[cInd] = i;
        cInd++;
      }
    }


    //generate random indexes without repetiotion that should be selected from currentR
    //this indexes help us to save r value in these positions and others indexes for this r
    //set to -1
    int value[NumberOfRandomS];
    for (int i=NumberOfRandomS-1; i>=0; --i)
    {
        int check; //variable to check or index is already used for this r
        size_t pick_index; //variable to store the random index in
        do
        {
        
        pick_index = rand() % lenShellR;
        //check or index is already used for this r:
        check=1;
        for (int j=0;j<i;++j)
            if (pick_index == value[j]) //if index is already used
            {
                check=0; //set check to false
                break; //no need to check the other elements of value[]
            }
        } while (check == 0); //loop until new, unique index is found
        value[i]=pick_index; //store the generated index in the array
        RandomIndex[i] = currentR[pick_index];
    }

    //set all positions for each r that are not on random selected to -1
    for(register int k=lenShellR-1; k >= 0; --k)
    {
      int flag = 0; // flag will be 1 if this index for this r in RandomIndex
      for (register int q = NumberOfRandomS-1; q >= 0; --q) 
      { 
        if(RandomIndex[q]== currentR[k]){
          flag = 1; //this index is found
        }
      }
      if(flag != 1)
      {
        //index for this r not in RandomIndex, so set this index for this r to -1
        pix_r[currentR[k]] = -1; 
      }
    }

  }
  return;
}
```

I will be very thankful if you help and explain what and how I can improve this function.

Comment: "register int" , don't use the "register" keyword unless you really know what you are doing. Typically the compiler makes better choices.

Comment: Are you using compiler optimization? Do you have a particular performance goal in mind? Is concurrency an option? Have you profiled your code?

Comment: @PiRocks, not exactly, I am not experienced in C-profiling, it is the first task, before I used Python and this change is...completely difficult

Comment: For profiling, look into the linux utility called perf, as well as fancier cross platform tools like vtune(though vtune is quite an advanced tool). A common pitfall of those tools is forgetting -fno-omit-frame-pointer.

Comment: I don't exactly follow your code with a quick read through, but you seem to have a number of deeply nested loops. Typically these can be avoided with better data structures, or more simply sorting arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The code is rather messy and hard to follow, so I can't be bothered to figure out what it actually does. The algorithm overall might be the true bottleneck. Anyway, here's some misc comments & advise of potential problems that I spotted:

- Ensure to only call `srand` once in the whole program.
- The `register` keyword is obsolete, from a time when compilers were bad at determining when to place variables in registers. Nowadays, compilers are more competent at this than programmers, don't use `register`, it is bloat.
- Similarly, replacing up-counting loops with down-counting ones for the sake of performance is an obsolete technique nowadays sorting under "pre-mature optimization". The compiler can do that optimization for you - so write the code as readable as possible instead.
- Avoid iterating over the same range/array multiple times.
- Keep loop conditions as trivial as possible. This helps readability and data cache optimization both. The ideal for loop should look like `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`.
- `malloc` is much slower than static or local storage. In this case you have a few items and only need to access them locally, so all `malloc` calls should be swapped with local arrays. You may use VLA here, to get stack allocation instead. That is, drop this code:

  ```
  int lenRandomIndex = NumberOfRandomS;
  int* RandomIndex = (int*) malloc(lenRandomIndex);
  memset(RandomIndex, 0, lenRandomIndex);
  ```

  and replace with this code:

  ```
  int RandomIndex [NumberOfRandomS];
  ```

  You have similar situations all over the code. And you probably don't need to set it to zero, because:
- Don't zero-initialize or `memset` arrays that you indeed to fill with data the first thing you do anyway. This is a rather big performance problem in the posted code.
- Empty `return ;` at the end of a function returning `void` is just clutter.
- Investigate if some of these searches could be replaced with binary search. It means sorting the data in advance but might lead to much faster code overall.
- Minimize the amount of checks, particularly inside loops.
- Split up your big monster functions into several. Local `static` functions are very certain to get inlined and they improve readability a lot. Splitting functions into several smaller also allows much easier benchmarking.

*Please benchmark your code when optimizations are enabled*.

Comment: Nit: can’t use an initializer with a VLA.